# Remove duplicate lines from multiple files

Tags: linux, bash

I want to compare the file "text.txt" with other files in a special directory, and remove duplicate strings only in the file "text.txt".

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried something? StackOverflow is not a _write-code-for-me_ site.

Comment: There are [commands](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) that might help you.

Comment: Your title says `Remove ... from multiple files` but your body says `remove ... only in the file "text.txt"`,  so what do you actually want?

Comment: I want to compare one file with multiple files in other directory!

Comment: Do you need to keep the order of the lines? If you cannot rephrase the problem, one approach could be to tag each line with the filename, then sort it all together on the line and tag in a way that the original filename ends up last, uniq, and then output only lines that have the tag of the original input file.

Comment: Maybe clarify the objective a bit better - do you want to filter out all the lines from `text.txt` which are contained in any of files in some other directory?

Answer (score 1):

Presume the files are located in "target" directory

```
perl -ne 'chomp;push (@x,$_);END{$ENV{R}= "^(".join("|",@x).")";system qq(perl -i.bak -pe "if (/\x0a/){s/$ENV{R}\x0a//g}else{s/$ENV{R}//g};" target/*)}' test.txt
```

Becareful! the code is not fully tested, backup your files before execution

Answer (score 1):

If the order of lines is not important (bash):

```
comm -23 <( <text.txt sort ) <( cat directory/* | sort ) > text.txt.uniques
```

If the order is important, the lines can be tagged with `nl`, then `join` would have to be used to find the same lines, then `sort -n` on the output and `cut` to get rid of the numbers.